# pyinstaller "unable to find a txt file when adding a binary"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When i was converting my script to exe using pyinstaller i got an error:-

```
Unable to find "c:\users\praveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\importlib_resources\version.txt" when adding binary and data files
```

You can view the full error here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FmV5kdb7p6TgEZwKBFDmFIszC-Qha0BD/view?usp=sharing

my script has alot of imports, they are:-

```
import tkinter as tk  
import os 
import time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract 
import webview
```

what does that error mean? and why am i getting it?

Comment: which line is this coming from?

Comment: ok wait i will add the full error

Comment: done, i have added the whole error in a txt file

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4725

Comment: Ok i updated my pyinstaller, it worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the command correctly, example:

```
pyinstaller --add-data web_folder;web_folder --add-data db.sqlite;. gui.py
```

Description: title_of_folder_or_file;path_to_it (if your OS Windows use ";", else ":". On windows it's 100% but on linux or mac i don't know) for folder you need after ; set path to this folder, example `web_folder;web_folder`

Source - [Official Documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)